# Simulate a button click event when the enter key is pressed (during an opened modal)

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I have a modal in my code named `myModal`. Only when the modal is shown on pressing the `enter` on my keyboard, I want a button on my modal to be clicked. I have the following code,

HTML

```html
    <div data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header"></div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <table>                     
              <tr>
                <td>Username</td>
                <td style="padding:5px;">
                  <input type="text" id="hostUsername" name="hostUsername" value="root" readonly="readonly">
                </td>
              </tr>    
              <tr>
                <td>Password</td>
                <td style="padding:5px;">
                  <input type="password" id="hostPassword" name="hostPassword" value="KJFDKFGS">
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>                    
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="uncheck_host()" >Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="getDataBt" onclick="getData()">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

JavaScript

```javascript
    $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (event) {                  
      alert("BEFORE ENTER clicked");
      var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
      if(keycode == '13'){
        alert("AFTER ENTER clicked");
        $('#getDataBt').click();   
      }     
    });
```

Here the alert `"BEFORE ENTER clicked"` is alerted when the modal appears. But on pressing `enter` on the keyboard after the modal appears, the alert `"AFTER ENTER clicked"` is not alerted. I need some guidance on this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to check if the modal is open and enter key is pressed, simultaneously. Something like:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
  if ($("#myModal").hasClass('in') && (e.keycode == 13 || e.which == 13)) {
    alert("Enter is pressed");
  }
});
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yAzrs/56/)

Answer (score 7):

You should do as follow :

```
$('#myModal').on('keypress', function (event) {
  alert("BEFORE ENTER clicked");
  var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
  if(keycode == '13'){
    alert("AFTER ENTER clicked");
    $('#getDataBt').click();   
  }
});
```

or

`$('#myModal').on('keyup', function (event) { ..... });`

Comment: shown.bs.modal this is bootstrap modal event triggered when modal is shown. That is why your alert("BEFORE ENTER clicked"); alerted  when modal appears.

Answer (score 1):

For bootstrap 4, use philantrovert's solution but instead of `hasClass('in')` use `hasClass('show')`.